# How can I model a generic Jackson POJO with a field that is changing the name?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I interact with a set of APIs that all return a similar response:

```
{
    "common1": ...,
    "common2": ...,
    "common3": ...,
    "someList": [
        //polymorph objects here
    ]
}
```

Currently, I have a separate POJO for each of these responses. However I would like to factorize this in a common object since I always perform the same actions with such object and that makes a lot of code duplication.

Initially, I had thought to create a similar Jackson class:

```
public class CommonClass<T> {
    @JsonProperty("common1")
    private final CommonType1 common1;
    @JsonProperty("common2")
    private final CommonType2 common2;
    @JsonProperty("common3")
    private final CommonType3 common3;
    @JsonProperty("someList")
    private final List<T> someList;

    //constructor and getters here
}
```

This would work fine, except for an issue: the Json name of `someList` changes as well. Sometimes it's `someListA`, sometimes it's `someListB`... basically it changes depending on the type it contains.

That makes it impossible to follow this approach (at least I think) since I can't dynamically change the value of the `JsonProperty()` annotations in my POJO.

I know that I could create a base class and then multiple extensions of such class, each one with a different list (differently named), but that wouldn't be my ideal solution because I wouldn't be able to have a common getter to process the elements without downcasting to the concrete type of POJO that I'm handling.

Do you have any idea/suggestion/approach for such problem?

Comment: you can also use `@JsonSubTypes` https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: @Chaosfire would you write it as an answer? It's exactly what I was hoping for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of options for the name is not too long, you can use [JsonAlias](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html).

> Annotation that can be used to define one or more alternative names for a property, accepted during deserialization as alternative to the official name. Alias information is also exposed during POJO introspection, but has no effect during serialization where primary name is always used.

Example:

```
public class CommonClass<T> {
    @JsonProperty("common1")
    private final CommonType1 common1;
    @JsonProperty("common2")
    private final CommonType2 common2;
    @JsonProperty("common3")
    private final CommonType3 common3;
    @JsonProperty("someList")//official name, used during serialization
    @JsonAlias({"someListA", "someListB"})//aliases used during deserialization, if the official name was not found
    private final List<T> someList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to deserialize it as a `Map<String, Object>` and than treat your map the same way except when retrieving someList* property instead of looking for a particular key such as `someListA` or `SomeListB` just search for the key that starts with `"someList"` prefix

Comment: I have oversimplified my example but the name is not even similar (there's not something like a common prefix). Also doing this seems to make me lose the automatic parsing coming from Jackson

Comment: why would it make you loose automatic parsing? it just gets parsed into a map

Comment: Because each different object parsed would simply be an object, I would have to cast it to a specific type before being able to manipulate it and that's specifically what I wanted to avoid (else even a custom serialiser/deserialiser would have worked). I wanted to still keep Jackson doing the mapping of the JSON to my classes even when I didn't know what a specific element was